# Как динамически поменять настройки для plupload

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть чек-бокс, при нажатии на который нужно поменять настройку для plupload - unique_names.
Не получается уничтожить upload, если он создан, и создать заново, если нет, при переключении. Опущу весь не нужный код, запощу только код при нажитии на чекбокс:

```
console.log(uploader);
if (typeof uploader != 'undefined') {
    uploader.destroy();
}
console.log(uploader);
```

....
При загрузке страницы запускается код.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                runtimes : 'html5',
                drop_element : 'dropbox',
                browse_button : 'dropbox',
                max_file_size : '10mb',
                chunk_size : '1mb',
                unique_names : true,
                multiple_queues:true,
                url : 'upload.php',
              });
```

При uploader.destroy(); он почему то не уничтожается!

Или как можно по-другому динамически изменить свойство uploader.settings.unique_names до загрузки файлов?

Answer (score 1):

Может так попробовать?

```
uploader.settings.unique_names = false;
uploader.refresh();
```

Comment: К сожалению не робит.. объект меняется, а продолжает загружать по выставленным заранее данным.